# Audioplayers package working on Chome DevTool but not on Android phone

Tags: flutter

Tested the following code on Chrome DevTool and the sound played with success but got an error in return when tested in on Android phone. How to make it work for android?

Package is audioplayers: ^5.1.0

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(UrlSource('lib/assets/audio/warm-piano-logo-116098.mp3'));
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      width: 80,
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xffde9b8d),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: const Center(child: 
          Text('Notation', 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
    ),
    )
```

Debugging message is as follows:

```
D/ViewRootImpl(25865): enqueueInputEventMotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=766.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2312986815, downTime=2312986815, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](25865): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=766.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2312986815, downTime=2312986815, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](25865): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, 
y[0]=766.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2312986815, downTime=2312986815, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](25865): processMotionEvent MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=766.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2312986907, downTime=2312986815, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](25865): dispatchPointerEvent handled=true, event=MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=766.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2312986907, downTime=2312986815, deviceId=-1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
V/MediaPlayer(25865): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(25865): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
E/flutter (25865): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, lib/assets/audio/warm-piano-logo-116098.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), java.io.FileNotFoundException: lib/assets/audio/warm-piano-logo-116098.mp3: 
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
E/flutter (25865):      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
E/flutter (25865):      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1276)
E/flutter (25865):      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1242)
E/flutter (25865):      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1207)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.source.UrlSource.setForMediaPlayer(UrlSource.kt:16)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.setSource(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:53)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.setSource(WrappedPlayer.kt:29)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.methodHandler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:126)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$methodHandler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:29)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (25865):      at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:75)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
E/flutter (25865):      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
E/flutter (25865): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:170)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:170)
E/flutter (25865):      at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8165)
E/flutter (25865):      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
E/flutter (25865):      ... 20 more
E/flutter (25865): , null)
E/flutter (25865): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (25865): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #2      AudioPlayer._completePrepared (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:316:5)
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #3      AudioPlayer.setSourceUrl (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:328:5)
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #4      AudioPlayer.setSource (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:299:5)
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25865): #5      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:194:5)
E/flutter (25865): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Tried in on android emulator, didn't work as well.
Tried to troubleshoot using ChatGPT, but with no success as well.

Comment: Please share correct package name

Comment: audioplayers: ^5.1.0